# Can i come back to Poland if I leave Poland just before my visa expires and have already applied for TRC

Tags: visas, poland, visa-expiration, visa-bans, return

My visa will expire soon but i have applied for TRC and have a stamp of the same.. I want to return back to India. Will there be any consequence in returning back to the country in the future..??
Will there be any ban over me if i stay beyond my visa period with a TRC application stamp..??